# Proof: finite subset closed under product of G is subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading Herstein on abstract algebra. I have a problem with the following proof:

[image]

Now, I understand the first part I think:

As there are more elements $a^k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n+1$ than the size of $H$, there must be $a^i$ and $a^j$ such that $a^i = a^j$. And as $j - i \geq 1 \implies a^{j-i}$ must be some $a^k$. But $a^j = a^i$ so $a^{j-i} = e$. And because as previously shown that $a^{j-i} \in H$ we now know that $e \in H$.

The second part now I do not quite follow; he states that because $j - i - 1 \geq 0$, $a^{j-i-1}$ has to be in $H$... Why? We know $a \in H$ (because $H$ is not empty), and then of course iterating $a$ with the product how many times we want is in $H$ as well, but that is $a^k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus{\{0\}}$. So why would $a^0$ be guaranteed to be in $H$. That is what he is saying there.

Comment: $a^0=e$ which is in H as shown in third last line.

Comment: why $a^0 = e$? We only showed $a^{j-i} = e$, why does that impliy that $j - i = 0$?

Comment: $e$ is the identity element. It does not imply that $j-i=0$. $a^0=a^1 \cdot a^{-1}=e$.

Comment: well then for that we would need $i = j = 1$, but the proof does not show that.

Comment: Absolutely not. $a^n=a^m$ does not imply $n=m$. In fact, $a^0=e$ is trivial for all groups and for all $a$. For example, let $G=\mathbb Z_3$. Then $2^0=0$ and $2^3=2+2+2=0$ but $3 \neq 0$.

Comment: This is just be definition? Because I still don't see how otherwise $a^{j-i}=e$ would imply that $a^0 \in H$.

Comment: Because $a^0=e$ and $e=a^{j-i} \in H$. Thus, $a^0=a^{j-i} \in H$.

Comment: Alternatively you can say that $j-i-1\gt 0$ because the element $a $ is supposed to be different from $e$, so necessarily $a^{j-i-1}\in H$.

Comment: @MarcoLecci $j-i-1=0$ doesn't imply $a=e$. In fact, if $j-i-1=0$, then $a^{j-i-1}=a^0=e$ which has to be in $H$.

Comment: Now I am certainly confused. Why then does it say in the proof $j - i - 1 \geq  0$.

Comment: Why can't $j-i-1$ be $0$? $a \neq e$ only means that $a^1 \neq e$. It doesn't mean that $a^0 \neq e$. In fact $a^0=e$ for **every element** of **every group.** This simply follows from the fact that $a^0=a \cdot a^{-1}=e$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes but if $j-i-1=0 $ then $aa^{j-i-1}=e=aa^0=a$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but that part comes in the next line. Anyway, I think it is important to understand that $a^0=e$ and there is nothing wrong with the proof. It is not wise to just work around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try a possibly simpler proof:

Given $a\in H$, we know that

- $x\mapsto ax$ is a map $H\to H$ **because $H$ is closed under multiplication.**
- This map is injective **because $G$ is a group,** more specifically, $ax=ay$ implies $x=y$ because we can multiply with $a^{-1}\in G$ from the left.
- **Because $H$ is a finite set,** every injective map $H\to H$ is in fact a bijection.
  In particular, there exists $x\in H$ such that $ax=a$. It follows that $x=e$. But then there also exists $y\in H$ such that $ay=e$. It follows that $y=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $a^{j-i}$ *is* a power of $a$.

Since $j-i>0$ by assumption, it is an element of $H$, because all powers $a^k\in H$, when $k>0$ (easy proof by induction using closure).

Since we already know $a^{j-i}=e$, we have $e\in H$.

The second part is about showing $a^{-1}\in H$.

Suppose first that $j-i=1$. Then $e=a^{j-i}=a$; in this case, $a^{-1}=e=a\in H$.

Otherwise $j-i>1$; if $k=j-i-1$, then $k>0$ and you can write
$$
e=aa^{j-i-1}=aa^k\in H
$$
Therefore $a^{-1}=a^k\in H$, because $H$ contains all powers of $a$ with positive exponent.

---

I prefer a different proof, which uses the pigeonhole principle in a different way.

By closure, for every $a\in H$, the map $\rho_a\colon H\to H$, $\rho_a(x)=ax$ is well defined.

By the group properties, $\rho_a$ is injective: if $\rho_a(x)=\rho_a(y)$, then $ax=ay$ and, multiplying by $a^{-1}$ (which exists in $G$), we get $x=y$. Since $H$ is finite, $\rho_a$ is surjective as well. Hence there exists $x\in H$ with $\rho_a(x)=ax=a$; therefore $e=x\in H$. There also exists $y\in H$ with $\rho_a(y)=ay=e$, so $a^{-1}=y\in H$.

Hence we have proved, only using non emptiness, closure and finiteness of $H$ that $e\in H$ and that, for every $a\in H$, $a^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: I think you should *highlight* the fact that there are actually "two cases" to part (2) (Herstein does a poor job of this): case 1) $j - i - 1 > 0$ and case 2 )$j - i - 1 = 0$, and that in the latter case, we have $e = a^{j-i} = a^1 = a$ (this avoids the reasoning $a^{j-i-1} = a^0 = e$, which is problematic, as we are limiting ourselves to *positive powers* in $H$). This is not to say you're wrong (you aren't), but this whole $a^0 = e$ *identity* seems to be something the OP is struggling with.

Comment: @DavidWheeler The division into cases was already there, but I changed the order according to your advice.

Comment: Well, if it helps, I was going to post my own answer, but after reading yours carefully, I decided instead to comment on yours and upvote it. Cheers.